# Crear nuevo documento de excel con asp.net a partir de una plantilla

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Tengo que llenar un reporte en excel en el que me piden mi nombre y hacen unas preguntas en las que debo calificar del 1 al 5 mi experiencia como usuario, pero no puedo modificar el archivo original así que debo crear un nuevo documento de excel a partir de el documento que ya está hecho y modificarlo, pero no tengo ni la mas mínima idea de como hacerlo, ya busqué en google pero solo encuentro formas de hacerlo modificando el archivo original, o creando un nuevo documento en blanco, pero nada parecido a lo que necesito. ¿Podrian ayudarme dándome ideas de cómo es que puedo lograr eso?

Answer (score 0):

Si ya sabes como editar un documento Excel, puedes crear una copia a partir del documento original y modificar dicha copia.

Mira este enlace, te servirá de ejemplo:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: veré si eso me resuelve algo, gracias